# Android Animation startOffset, but with starting position

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

here is my animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1200"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:repeatCount="4"/>
</set>
```

so what this animation basically does, is that image grows from size 0, until it reaches original size.

so I want to wait for 0.5(as you can see in startOffset) seconds when animation is done, it waits, but starts with image with size 0. I want it to wait 0.5 in its original size and then start disappearing and appearing. something like endOffset instead of startOffset

Comment: Set fromXScale and fromYScale to 0.5

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >
<scale
    android:duration="1200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="4"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```